# How can I use options for a ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions

Using this command I can plot three different curves using **ParametricPlot3D**

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{t x, Sin[t x], 0}, {0 , Sin[t x], t x }, {t x ,Sin[t x], t x }}, {t, 0, Pi}, {x, 0, 4}]
```

However, my output result is coming out crooked. How can I fix it?
The command `ViewPoint` does not work as in `Plot3D` or `DensityPlot`, There are some specific commands?

The idea is to obtain something like that. This plot was generated using my code. but it was obtained using paint. The resolution is awful.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean `ViewPoint` does not work? Can you give us an example where `ViewPoint` works in `Plot3D`, but it does not work in `ParametricPlot3D`?

Comment: Perhaps you mean [`ViewVertical`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewVertical.html)? Also consider reparametrizing to 1 variable so the plotter knows it's actually a 1D curve: `ParametricPlot3D[{{s, Sin[s], 0}, {0, Sin[s], s}, {s, Sin[s], s}}, {s, 0, 4 Pi}, Lighting -> "Neutral", ViewVertical -> {0, -1, 0}, ViewPoint -> {1.4, -1.3, -2.8}, ImageSize -> 700] /. Line -> Tube`

Answer (score 1):

To add to Chips answer, sometimes the option AxesEdge is helpful and a few other clues in case someone isn't sure which axis is which:

`ParametricPlot3D[{{t x, Sin[t x], 0}, {0, Sin[t x], t x}, {t x, 
   Sin[t x], t x}}, {t, 0, Pi}, {x, 0, 4}, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, AxesEdge -> {{0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}}, 
 AxesStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{s, 0, Sin[s]}, {0, s, Sin[s]}, {s, s, Sin[s]}}, {s, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Tube[.07], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
axes[x_, y_, z_, f_, a_] := 
 Graphics3D[
  Join[{Red, Arrowheads[a]}, 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}]] & /@ {{x, 0, 0}, {0, y, 0}, {0, 0, 
      z}}, {Text[
     Style["x", FontSize -> Scaled[f]], {0.9*x, 0.1*y, 0.1*z}], 
    Text[Style["y", FontSize -> Scaled[f]], {0.1 x, 0.9*y, 0.1*z}], 
    Text[Style["z", FontSize -> Scaled[f]], {0.1*x, 0.1*y, 0.9*z}]}]]
Show[{(ParametricPlot3D[{{s, Sin[s], 0}, {0, Sin[s], s}, {s, Sin[s], 
       s}}, {s, 0, 4 Pi}, Lighting -> "Neutral", ImageSize -> 700] /. 
    Line -> Tube), axes[10, 10, 10, 0.05, 0.02]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 10}, {-5, 10}, {-5, 10}}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, 2}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```